# Accessing Spatial Analyst extension from stand alone script?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, error-000824

If I run this script:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial"))
from arcpy.sa import Con
from arcpy import env
fDir=r'd:\scratch\fdir'
outFolder=r'd:\aerials\images'
env.workspace = outFolder
fDir=arcpy.Raster(fDir)
Gter=Con(fDir> 1,2)
Gter.save("TEST")
```

from ArcGIS, the output is:

[image]

When I run it as stand-alone script, it is very different story:

[image]

How do I access Spatial Analyst extension from a stand alone script?

Comment: Here is a [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54044/arcgis-10-1-error-000824-the-tool-is-not-licensed-in-arcpy) to a similar issue with the same error. The one answer on the page suggests importing the arcinfo module.

Comment: I have "Editor' whatever the latest name for this, so results as expected. gp.setProduct("ArcInfo") error when run from ArcGIS when I added arcinfo, Tool not licensed in stand alone mode. I am gutted, it means that there is no way to use multiple processors for some time consuming tasks, where extensions involved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method I use is:

```
if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
    arcpy.AddMessage("Checking out Spatial")
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
else:
    arcpy.AddError("Unable to get spatial analyst extension")
    arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages(0))
    sys.exit(0)
```

and then at the end of your script:

```
arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```

which is generically what Ken said, the issue here seems to be that for some external reason arcpy cannot get a license... when using `arcpy.sa` in a standalone script it is possible to have more than one license checked out (perhaps that's a bug worth reporting to Esri).. check your task manager to ensure there's not ArcCatalog/ArcMap that's half crashed and still holding a license, script windows that have not been exited and also editors that have imported arcpy (PyWin does this if you `import arcpy` in the interactive window).

Worst case restart your computer... it's amazing how many things that fixes.

Comment: I don' understand  how adding arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial") at the end of the script can help, if script never gets to the end. Yes, I applied restarting 'approach' multiple times, not helping. Can it be the type of license, that is floating?

Comment: Sorry, the whole point of this answer has been missed.. you've already done everything you need and *should* be getting your extension (well, you need to add arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial") to *actually* get the extension rather than arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") which will only tell you if it is available) but Ken already said that. The point is that the standalone script can consume a 2nd extension license to your ArcGis - to me this is a bug but it may be intentional. The text gives a guide on what to look for to free up the license from ArcGis so you standalone can grab it.

Comment: As you put it 'intentional' bug, no matter what I do, and number of licenses available

Comment: Can you edit your question with your current code please. Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: In reply to your answer I said "Yes, I applied restarting 'approach' multiple times, not helping". Will post latest script later. Did you manage to make it work from stand-alone script? Modify your Q, I am more than happy to accept it. Just try my example

Comment: Yes, frequently. It always works for me (though sometimes I get angry I.T. administrators asking me why I can take two licenses on the same user name and computer name).

Comment: So stand-alone and ArcGIS competing for license. If yes, I have to give up, we've got 2 for the big crowd...

Comment: Reserve your scripts for after you go home.. multiple command windows can share the same license but it seems that ArcGis (multiple instances) do not share. I generally leave spatial analyst turned off and activate/release in the script *as required*, but then again I don't use spatial analyst tools interactively. Or write your tools to be executed in a toolbox, then they have no problem with sharing the extension.

Comment: It was about multiprocessing, thus evening might work, toolbox - won't. Case closed, thank you

Answer (score 3):

I believe you also have to check out the extension.

```
import arcpy
import sys

if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    from arcpy.sa import Con
    from arcpy import env
    fDir=r'd:\scratch\fdir'
    outFolder=r'd:\aerials\images'
    env.workspace = outFolder
    fDir=arcpy.Raster(fDir)
    Gter=Con(fDir> 1,2)
    Gter.save("TEST")
else:
    arcpy.AddMessage("No Spatial Analyst Extension avaialable.")
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Message is the same: The tool is not licensed

Comment: Do you have more than one Spatial Analyst license? Your open ArcMap session might be holding the extension license.

Comment: I have floating license. I've tried to quit ArcGIS and I can see that there is one available, still no luck. License available, tool not licensed

Comment: @FelixIP Did you ever solve the problem? Just wondering. I have tried everything on stackexchange and it doesnot work.

Comment: Close all arcgis things on the computer, kill relevant services, run stand-alone script