# Error in <module> arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, error-000824

I am writing a Python code and have trouble adding a layer to the program. I face this problem below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\arcpy workspace\python learning codes\loc.py", line 5, in <module>
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('inf1', 'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE', 'inf2' , '5000 Meters' , 'NEW_SELECTION')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 4381, in SelectLayerByLocation
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation).
```

What's the problem with adding a layer or anything else that makes it go wrong?

Comment: @HDunn without a code snippet it's hard to say this is duplicate when there's no mention of an extension.  As it is `SelectLayerByLocation` doesn't require a separate or higher-tier license...

Comment: @maryam please [edit] your Question and include a snippet of your code that is failing.  Are you using any ArcGIS extensions in your script?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is detailed in the error, you do not have a adequate spatial analysis license. please [see a previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151166/how-to-access-spatial-analyst-extension-from-stand-alone-script) in gis.stackechange